# Non-defective matrix proof

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove that if two non-defective matrices $A$ and $B$ are non-defective, so is $A + B$? I have tried looking at this through diagonalization but am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming based on [this](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Defective_matrix) that nondefective means diagonalizable.

This is false consider $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$ and $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&1}$. The first is diagonalizable, the second has eigenvalues $0$ and $1$ for eigenvectors $\pmatrix{1 \\ 0}$ and $\pmatrix{1\\ 1}$, so it is also diagonalizable, but their sum is a nondiagonal matrix in Jordan canonical form, so it is not diagonalizable, and hence is defective.

[Source](http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?forumID=13&threadID=104436&messageID=534165)